# Самое длинное междометие

Tags: междометие

Наткнулась в Интернете на такое утверждение: "Самое длинное междометие, включённое в Грамматический словарь — «физкульт-привет» (15 или 14 букв в зависимости от статуса дефиса)".
Честно говоря, трудно поверить, что "физкульт-привет" - это именно междометие. И, если так, то любое приветствие можно отнести к междометиям? Например, "здравствуйте", "до свидания" и т.д. - это разве междометия?  
Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить мои сомнения.

Answer (score 4):

"Физкульт-привет" относится к этикетным междометиям.

В русском языке существует три лексико-грамматических разряда междометий:

1) эмоциональные (ай, ах, ого),

2) императивные (айда, марш, стоп),

3) этикетные (здравствуй, до свидания, спасибо).

Answer (score 1):

"Здравствуйте" и "до свидания" – междометия. А что же такое "здравствуйте" – повелительное наклонение глагола, что ли? Оно уже давным-давно так не воспринимается. Как и "спасибо", например.